# File upload progress not being updated in the observable or completed before the observable is ready

Tags: angular, rxjs, subject-observer

Below is a snippet of code that calls the function below.  This is a process that allows people to drag and drop files from the system to the website.  It displays a list of all the files with a progress bar as they are loaded.  It works fine most of the time but when there are a large number of files I run into some problems.  I have a test directory that I am loading that has over 100 files in it.  The first files that are getting loaded are pretty small so it seems that they are getting loaded before the observable is getting set up because the progress bar does not show any progress and the forkJoin does not complete but if I look on the system the files are actually loaded.

Am I not setting the Subject up correctly?  Is there a better way to track the progress of files that are being uploaded?  Any help would be appreciated.

```
if (this.files.size > 0) {
  this.progress = await this.uploadService.dndUpload(
    this.files, this.currentDir, this.currentProject, timestamp
  );
  let allProgressObservables = [];
  for (let key in this.progress) {
    allProgressObservables.push(this.progress[key].progress);
  }

  this.sfUploadSnackbar.openSnackbar(this.files, this.progress);

  forkJoin(allProgressObservables).subscribe(async end => {
    this.sfUploadSnackbar.closeSnackbar();
    this.uploadService.clearUploadDir(this.currentProject, timestamp)
      .subscribe();
    this.uploadInProgress = false;
    this.getFiles();
  });
}





 async dndUpload(files: Set<any>, dir: string, projectId: number, timestamp: number) {
    const status: { [key: string]: { progress: Observable<number> } } = {};

    for (let it = files.values(), file = null; file = it.next().value;) {

      let params = new HttpParams()
        .set('dir', dir)
        .set('path', file.fullPath.replace(file.name,''))
        .set('projectId', projectId.toString())
        .set('timestamp', timestamp.toString());
      let f: File = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => file.file(resolve, reject))
      const formData: FormData = new FormData();
      formData.append('file', f, f.name);

      const req = new HttpRequest('POST', '/api/dndUpload', formData, {
        reportProgress: true, params
      });

      const progress = new Subject<number>();

      status[file.name] = {
        progress: progress.asObservable()
      };

      this.http.request(req).subscribe(event => {
        if (event.type === HttpEventType.UploadProgress) {

          const percentDone = Math.round(100 * event.loaded / event.total);

          progress.next(percentDone);
        } else if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {

          progress.complete();
        }
      });
    }

    return status;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for `forkJoin` to complete, you must make sure that all of the provided observables complete.
What might happen is that `forkJoin` subscribes too late to the `Subject`s from `allProgressObservables`.

I assume that `this.sfUploadSnackbar.openSnackbar(this.files, this.progress);` will subscribe to `this.progress` in order to receive the percent for each file.

Here's an idea:

```js
dndUpload (files: Set<...>/* ... */): Observable<any> {
  // Note that there are no subscriptions
  return [...files].map(
    f => from(new Promise((resolve, reject) => file.file(resolve, reject)))
      .pipe(
        map(f => (new FormData()).append('file', f, f.name)),
      )
  )
}

const fileObservables$ = this.dndUpload(files);

const progressObservables$ = fileObservables$.map(
  (file$, fileIdx) => file$.pipe(
    switchMap(formData => {
      const req = /* ... */;

      return this.http.request(req)
        .pipe(
          filter(event.type === HttpEventType.UploadProgress),
          // Getting the percent
          map(e => Math.round(100 * e.loaded / e.total)),
          tap(percent => this.updatePercentVisually(percent, fileIdx))
        )
    })
  )
);

// Finally subscribing only once to the observables
forkJoin(progressObservables$).subscribe(...);
```

Notice there are a few changes:

- I stopped using a `Subject` for each file

  - as a consequence, `this.sfUploadSnackbar.openSnackbar(this.files, this.progress);` had to be replaced with another approach(`this.updatePercentVisually`)
- the subscription of the file observables happens in only once place, in `forkJoin`;

`this.http.request` will complete when the request fulfills, so `forkJoin` should be able to complete as well, allowing you to do the 'cleanups'(removing loading progress etc...).

Comment: Andrei Gatej I think I understand most of this and the problem that I am running into is my dndUpload functiion an error is thrown on the return statement saying Type 'Observable<void>[]' is missing the following properties from type 'Observable<any>': _isScalar, source, operator, lift, and 5 more.  I have been searching the web but haven't found any solution yet.  Do you have any suggestions.  I really appreciate this because it looks like I am very close with your help to a solution.

Comment: Then it should be Observable<any>[] instead of Observable<any>(the return type of the fn). Does it work?

Comment: Yes that take care of my error at least.  Now I can continue with my testing.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: It is not reaching the second map.  I verified that it was getting to the from.  Here is my code:

`
  dndUpload (files: Set<any>): Observable<any>[] {

    return [...files].map(

      file => from(new Promise((resolve, reject) => file.file(resolve, reject)))

        .pipe(

          map((f: File) => (new FormData()).append('file', f, f.name))

        )

    )

  }`

I had to type the parameter for the second map so that I could use it in the append for the FormData.  Is this causing me a problem?

Comment: I forgot that `FormData.append` [returns void](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append). It should be `map(f => { const fd = new FormData(); fd.append(...); return fd })`;

Comment: That maybe would have been the next item but it never even get to the map function.  I can put a console.log as the first line of the function but it does not reach it.  It is almost like the .pipe after the from is not working.

Comment: Hmm, there must be a problem inside ‘file.file’. Are you sure that promise resolves? Also, I think it would be better to open a discussion

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210753/discussion-between-gary-dickerson-and-andrei-gtej).

Answer (score 0):

I accepted the answer of @Andrei above because if it hadn't been for him I may have never quit hitting my head against the wall.  I include my actual code that I ended up using below just as reference for anyone else that might run into a similar problem in the future.  Probably many improvement that can be made yet but at least it works.

```
if (this.files.size > 0) {
  const status: { [key: string]: { progress: BehaviorSubject<number> } } = {};
  const allProgressObservables = [];
  for (let f of this.files) {
    const progress = new BehaviorSubject<number>(0);
    status[f.fullPath] = {progress: progress};
    allProgressObservables.push(status[f.fullPath].progress);
  }
  this.sfUploadSnackbar.openSnackbar(this.files, status);
  forkJoin(allProgressObservables)
    .subscribe(() => {
      this.sfUploadSnackbar.closeSnackbar();
    });
  from(this.files)
    .pipe(
      mergeMap(async (file) => {
        let params = new HttpParams()
          .set('dir', this.currentDir)
          .set('path', file.fullPath.replace(file.name,''))
          .set('projectId', this.currentProject.toString())
          .set('timestamp', timestamp.toString());
        let f: File = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => file.file(resolve))
        const formData: FormData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', f, f.name);
        const req = new HttpRequest('POST', '/api/dndUpload', formData, {
          reportProgress: true, params
        });
        return this.http.request(req)
          .subscribe(event => {
            if (event.type === HttpEventType.UploadProgress) {
              const percentDone = Math.round(100 * event.loaded / event.total);
              status[file.fullPath].progress.next(percentDone);
            } else if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
              status[file.fullPath].progress.complete();
            }  
          });
      })
    ).subscribe();
}
```